# How to count days of year PHP to create day range array wrapping past day 365 to day 1

Tags: php, date, range

I have a database table with content for each day of the year and I'm trying to return the current day and the next 9 days to my PHP app.

```
Day 1 = Lorem ipsum
Day 2 = Lorem ipsum
Day 3 = Lorem ipsum
Day 365 = Lorem ipsum
```

I have a basic function that gets the current day of year in PHP and creates an array of the subsequent 10 days:

```
$today = date(z);
$subsequent_days = 9;
$days_arr = range($today, $today+$subsequent_days);
```

**Example:** If today is `12/27`, the day number is `360`, the resulting array is `(360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369)`

The problem I'm trying to solve is that when I feed that array into my database query to get the current and upcoming 9 days, if the current date is less than 10 days from the end of the year (as in the example above) then it only returns me that many days back.

What I'm looking for is a simple/clean way to have the `days_arr` stop at 365 and restart at 1 to complete the 10 values in the returned array.

So the end result I'm looking for is: `(360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 1, 2, 3, 4)`

Comment: do you need to account for leap years?  Can't you just do an additional scrub through the array and use the modulo `%` operator (assuming that your array isn't going to scale to thousands of elements)?

Comment: a for loop, and if day = 365, then day = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution can be achieved using modulo `%` operator.  Using `range()` is convenient, but doesn't give you the flexibility of using modulo.  Not sure if you need to account for leap years, so adding it as an arg:

```
<?php

$day_seq = function($start, $isleap) {

    // Convert human's 1-indexed day to zero-indexed day
    $start--;
    $numdays = $isleap ? 366 : 365;
    // Build 10-day sequence, adding 1 to re-calibrate to human's 1-indexed counting
    for($seq = [], $i = 0; $i<10; $i++) {
        $seq[] = (($start + $i) % $numdays) + 1;
    }

    return $seq;
};

print_r($day_seq(360,0));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 360
    [1] => 361
    [2] => 362
    [3] => 363
    [4] => 364
    [5] => 365
    [6] => 1
    [7] => 2
    [8] => 3
    [9] => 4
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the modular operator:

```
<?php
$ten_days = function($from) {
    for(
        $range = [], $i = 0; 
        $i<10;
        $range[] = ($from + $i) % 365, $i++
    );

    return $range;
};

var_export($ten_days(360));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 360,
  1 => 361,
  2 => 362,
  3 => 363,
  4 => 364,
  5 => 0,
  6 => 1,
  7 => 2,
  8 => 3,
  9 => 4,
)
```

Note: This is assuming a year of 365 days, 0 indexed.  You will have to adjust for leap years.

You can adjust the for loop above for 1 indexed days:

```
for(
    $range = [], $i = -1; 
    $i<9;
    $range[] = ($from + $i) % 365 + 1, $i++
);
```